# Does a finite ring's additive structure and the structure of its group of units determine its ring structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite commutative rings with unity. Denote the additive group structure of each to be $A^{(+)}$ and $B^{(+)}$, and the multiplicative group of units of each to be $A^{(\times)}$ and $B^{(\times)}$ respectively. Supposing that $A^{(+)}\cong B^{(+)}$ and $A^{(\times)}\cong B^{(\times)}$, does it follow then that $A\cong B$?

Comment: I think [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7133/classification-of-finite-commutative-rings) could be useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.  Suppose that $p$ is an odd prime, and consider $A = \mathbb F_p[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and $B = \mathbb F_p[z]/(z^3)$.

In each case the addive group is isomorphic to a direct sum of 3 copies of
a cyclic group of order $p$, while the multiplicative group is isomorphic
to a direct product of a cyclic group of order $(p-1)$ and two cyclic groups of
order $p$.

Comment: That's a nice counterexample. An obvious follow-up would then be, is there a nice characterisation of rings for which the statement does hold?

Comment: $A\ncong B$ as rings, since the number of elements $f$ with $f^2=0$ is $p^2$ in $A$ and $p$ in $B$. But where is $p\neq2$ actually needed?

Comment: @LeonLampret  Dear Leon, Actually, I don't think it's needed.  Regards,

Comment: Also, how do you see that $A^\times\cong B^\times$? I know that $A^\times=\{a+bx+cy;a\neq0\}$ and $B^\times=\{a+bz+cz^2;a\neq0\}$ with
$$(a+bx+cy)(d+ex+fy)=ad+(ae+bd)x+(af+cd)y~~~\text{ and}$$
$$(a+bz+cz^2)(d+ez+fz^2)=ad+(ae+bd)z+(af+be+cd)z^2$$
But what are the isomorphisms to $C_{p−1}\times C_p\times C_p$?

Comment: Dear Leon, Each of these rings has a natural projection to $\mathbb F_p$, which induces a surjection of the units onto $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$; call the kernel $U$.  It's easy to see in each case that $U^p = 1$ (actually, maybe *here* is where I needed $p$ odd!).  So $U$ is an ab. group of order $p^2$ and killed by $p$, hence a product of two cyclic groups of order $p$.  So each unit group is an extension of $C_{p-1}$ by $C_p \times C_p$, and any such extension splits (easily checked).  Regards,