# Why are residue rings of prime ideals in algebraic number fields determined by their additive structure and the structure of their group of units?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have been trying to plough through [this paper](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~ryro9206/aux/doc/eir.pdf) by Elia, Interlando and Rosenbaum, and there is something that I don't quite understand. In proving a structure theorem for residue rings of unramified primes, they prove that a given residue ring of a prime ideal, $\zeta(\beta^a)$ is isomorphic additively to some ring, say $A$, and then that its group of units is isomorphic to $A^{(x)}$. This apparently suffices to prove the structure theorem.

Why is this?

Looking through the stackexchange archives this doesn't to always be true in general: [Does a finite ring's additive structure and the structure of its group of units determine its ring structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35358/does-a-finite-rings-additive-structure-and-the-structure-of-its-group-of-units-d) What's different here?

Comment: I read through this and I'm a bit hung up on Thm 5 as well.  In general, isomorphisms should be proven with actual maps.